# jQuery UI autocomplete fix suggestions width

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is it possible to auto adjust suggestions width?

[image]

- Windows Server 2008 should be on one line.

Code:

```
$('#tags').tagit({
    singleField: true,
    singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
    allowSpaces: true,
    minLength: 2,
    removeConfirmation: true,
    tagSource: function (request, response) {
        //console.log("1");
        $.ajax({
            url: "tagit/search.php",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            dataType: "json",
            max: 5,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.slice(0, 5), function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just replace the spaces within the values with non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @Vex I tried this but when i insert `&nbsp;` between values in database, suggestions will not be shown.

Comment: I wouldn't do it in the database, but do it when you add the items to the display list. Guessing from your code that would be when you set the `label`. So you'd have something like `label: item.value.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")`.

Comment: @Vex I tried your solution but i get this result: http://i.imgur.com/tLyUUVc.png

Comment: Try https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete plugin.  It should solve ALL your issues.

Comment: For now i use fixed size in my custom css `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:200px}`